# Oracle Invalid Number ORA-06512

Tags: c#, oracle11g, odp.net, ora-01722

I am trying to execute a packageprocedure from ODP.NET C# which insert data into the table and I am getting following error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   ORA-06512: at "TTS.EMP_PKG", line 86
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

Here is the Line 86 of that package:

```
UPDATE TTS.TRAN_EMPLOYEE_TBL 
   SET EMP_ID = EMPID, 
       FIRST_NAME = FIRSTNAME, 
       LAST_NAME = LASTNAME, 
       COMIT_ID = COMITID, 
       RACF_ID = RACFID,
       EMAIL_ID = EMAILID, 
       LOC_CITY = LOCCITY, 
       LOC_COUNTRY = LOCCOUNTRY, 
       REGION = REGION,
       USER_MODIFIED = USERMODIFIED, 
       DATE_MODIFIED = SYSDATE 
 WHERE TRAN_EMP_ID = 9440
```

All are varchar2 fields and also input params are also varchar2 type. Originally I had an input param for 9440 but when I got the above error I hard coded the number and I am still getting it.
Can you please help?

Comment: It looks like you and the database disagree on everything being a VARCHAR. Could you post the actual table schema?

Comment: Can you post the schema details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joachim Isaksson you are right.. I forgot that one of the columns in table is an integer and once I did to_number it's working again. Thank you for the help